# How to get form-control on the same line as the label?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can we get these two to appear on the same line?

[image]

I've tried everything!

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <span class="label label-primary"> Placement: </span>
  <%= f.number_field :order, class: "form-control", id: "two", placeholder: 'Put in Order' %>
</div>
</div>
```

I know it's something in the default setting with bootstrap. I've tried to override it with `inline-block` or `inline` for all the classes, but it made no difference.

Maybe you'll have better luck.

Comment: Please include the CSS that you have for all of those elements in your question as well.

Comment: did you try float left

Comment: Just use the class from bootstrap for horizontal forms: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Comment: do you have a fiddle?`inline-block` worked for me.

Comment: @TylerH I have nothing in my CSS from those elements. It's all bootstrap.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad didn't work :/

Comment: @Aguardientico I think you are onto something but it didn't work for me. I added the `<form class="form-horizontal">` above my code.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com give a look to my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using ruby (erb) so try something like the following (taken from http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal):

```
<%= form_for ... class="form-horizontal" do |f| %>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.label :order, 'Placement', class: 'col-sm-2 control-label label label-primary' %>
    <div class='col-sm-10'>
      <%= f.number_field :order, class: "form-control", id: "two", placeholder: 'Put in Order' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I get a SyntaxError tho for `<%= simple_form_for(@habit) class="form-horizontal" do |f| %>`:

Comment: /Users/galli01anthony/Desktop/Pecoce/app/views/habits/_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_class, expecting keyword_end ... simple_form_for(habit) class="form-horizontal" do |f| ou... ... ^ /Users/galli01anthony/Desktop/Pecoce/app/views/habits/_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_end ...bit) class="form-horizontal" do |f| output_buffer.safe_appe... ... ^ /Users/galli01anthony/Desktop/Pecoce/app/views/habits/_form.html.erb:76: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Comment: change `<%= simple_form_for(@habit) class="form-horizontal" do |f| %>` for `<%= simple_form_for(@habit, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>`

Answer (score 1):

try add form-inline class and or display:block-inline

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the form-horizontal class on your form tag as explained here.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal